# Angular2: make the browser call an api on a subdomain

Tags: node.js, angular, cross-domain

I serve a angular2 webapp from `mysite.com`

My webapp is making calls from the browser to a nodejs backend.

For the moment I use `mysite.com/api/` to call the api.

For system architecture reasons, I wish to call the api a different way, by using a subdomain:

```
api.mysite.com/
```

How can I get rid of the cross-origin issue?

Comment: Configure `api.mysite.com` to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header and any other `Access-Control-*` response headers that might be needed in your scenario. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: this only works for images or other static resources not for xhr requests. And we are talking about client side, not server side cors issues

Comment: If don’t have access to configure anything on `api.mysite.com` then you can’t “get rid of the cross-origin issue” without using a proxy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/42744707#42744707.

Comment: But if you do have access to configure the web server at `api.mysite.com` then you can configure it to make it work with cross-origin XHR requests. At a minimum, you just need to configure it to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header in the response. If it does, and your XHR request is a simple request that doesn’t trigger a preflight then that’s all you’d need to make it do.

Comment: Files are served by google cloud cdn on cloud storage buckets. I can set meta data so it should be fine. But I'm not sure my requests are only simple get requests. Will try tomorrow morning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use JsonP  take a look here : [Jsonp](https://ng2.codecraft.tv/http/jsonp-with-observables/):

```
 import { JsonP } from '@angular/http"; 
 @Injectable()
 export class dataService{
      constructor(jsonp:Jsonp) {

      }

      getData(){
        let url = 'http://api.mysite.com&c=JSONP_CALLBACK';
        jsonp.request(url, { method: 'Get' })
         .map( res => /...);
      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, will test this. Could you elaborate how this solves the cross origin issue, I think it can be useful for people :) thanks for the edit, very useful!

Comment: I'm not qualified, but you can refer to the wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: dont't forget to Import JsonpModule in you AppModule

Comment: Your link 403s?